# How to use Angular to detect all image sources in a parent div and add to an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am making a portfolio site for a friend. On the site are many different albums of work. The album is consisted of many thumbnails and on click the user can view the large resolution work and click left and right arrow buttons to view the rest of the work in the album.

Here is how the site is set up:

```
<div id="album-1" class="row">

        <!-- Work 1-->
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div style="background-image: url(images/Work/placeholders/1.jpg);"></div>
          </div>

        <!-- Work 2-->
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div style="background-image: url(images/Work/placeholders/2.jpg);"></div>
          </div>

        <!-- Work 3-->
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div style="background-image: url(images/Work/placeholders/3.jpg);">
            </div>
          </div>

</div>

<div id="album-2" class="row">

        <!-- Work 1-->
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div style="background-image: url(images/Work/placeholders/4.jpg);"></div>
          </div>

        <!-- Work 2-->
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div style="background-image: url(images/Work/placeholders/5.jpg);"></div>
          </div>

        <!-- Work 3-->
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div style="background-image: url(images/Work/placeholders/6.jpg);">
            </div>
          </div>

</div>
```

There are different albums each with a set of thumbnails.

So what I was thinking was

1. User clicks a thumbnail and an angular function is called.
2. The function detects all of the image sources in that specific album, adds "_full" after and adds it to a object

   ```
       IE: 

       $scope.pictures = 
       [
       "images/work/placeholders/1_full.jpg",
       "images/work/placeholders/2_full.jpg",
       "images/work/placeholders/3_full.jpg",
       "images/work/placeholders/4_full.jpg"
       ];
   ```
3. The viewer then is unhidden and displays the current picture.
4. On click of the left and right arrow the user can flip through the images in an object.

   ```
       $scope.image_change_right = function () {
       if ($scope.picture_value < ($scope.pictures.length-1))
       {
          $scope.picture_value = $scope.picture_value + 1;
          $scope.picture = $scope.pictures[$scope.picture_value];
          console.log($scope.picture_value);
       }
       else{
           $scope.picture_value = 0;
           $scope.picture = $scope.pictures[$scope.picture_value];
           console.log($scope.picture_value);
       }
   }
   ```

**So my main question is:

How can I have angular find all of the image files in the parent div and add them to an object?

Thank you for any help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature can be implemented using with out `angular`. Or you can put this code sample anywhere or call it using `ng-click`.

```
Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('[style^="background-image"]')
    ).map(el=>el.style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((.*)\)/,'$1')
          .replace(/"/g,'')
          .replace(/.jpg/,'_full.jpg')
          )
```

See the [output](http://jsbin.com/yidamewuze/edit?html,js,console,output).

You send any value based on the requirement to the querySelectorAll. get if from the `ng-click` followed by `$event`.

Hope this help in achieving your goal.

for angular

```
<div ng-click="getAllImages($event)">
  <!-- All child elements -->
</div>
```

In your angular function use the above logic($event.target.children). If you find better approach to do this please share it.

Comment: @benjamin-lawson ask me if you need any help regarding the code snippet.

Comment: Your code was simple, beautiful, and easy to understand. Thank you so much for your answer!